# jquery children attach remove edit input

Tags: javascript, jquery

to get more than what you expect may be nice on your birthday - but this in script drives you crazy... :(

i've got the following code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="id1" class="fragenMainDiv" style="width: 80%; margin: 0px;">
    <input type="button" id="id1_edit" class="editIcon" value="change">
    <span id="id1_Label" class="fragenLabel">
    <p>
    <span style="margin-left:5px;">
    <b>something</b>
    </span>
    </p>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
    showMain();
    });
    function showMain() {

    $('.editIcon').css("cursor", "pointer").click(function () {
    edit($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $('.editfinish').css("cursor", "pointer").click(function () {
    editFinish($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    }

    function edit(idTemp) {
    //alert(fragenidTemp);
    var IdArray = idTemp.split("_");
    var Id = IdArray[0]
    var inputValue = $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span").children("b").text();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span").children("b").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").append("<input id=input" + Id + " type=text size=70 style=margin-left:4px;></input><input type=button id=" + Id + " class=editfinish value=change />");

    $('input[id|="input' + Id + '"]').val(inputValue);
    $('.editIcon').hide();
    showMain();
    }


    function editFinish(Id) {
    var inhaltFrage = $('input[id|="input' + Id + '"]').val();
    $('.editIcon').show();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").children("input").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").children("img").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").append("<b>" + inhaltFrage + "</b>");

    showMain();
    }

    </script>

    </html>
```

what I want is an input field that reacts like a normal input field - but after the first (correct) change of value the form shows three times the input field...

Does someone have an idea? As it is a condensed script of a larger script so I need the structure of functions. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argghhh I finally found it. Dude you cannot use show main after every edit and editFinish. Becuse you are stacking several same event to one click ! The code shoul look like this :

```
function edit(idTemp) {
    //alert(fragenidTemp);
    var IdArray = idTemp.split("_");
    var Id = IdArray[0]
    var inputValue = $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span").children("b").text();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span").children("b").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").append("<input id=input" + Id + " type=text size=70 style=margin-left:4px;></input><input type=button id=" + Id + " class=editfinish value=change />");

    $('input[id|="input' + Id + '"]').val(inputValue);
    $('.editIcon').hide();
     $('.editfinish').css("cursor", "pointer").click(function () {
    editFinish($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    }


    function editFinish(Id) {
    var inhaltFrage = $('input[id|="input' + Id + '"]').val();
    $('.editIcon').show();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").children("input").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").children("img").remove();
    $('div[id|="' + Id + '"]').children("span").children("p").children("span:first").append("<b>" + inhaltFrage + "</b>");    }
```

Hope that you see the error now, if not i can explain in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply - i tried to change my script... but it didn't work... may I ask you to write the script down`?

Comment: Micheal instead of voting up you changed the correct answer and took down my rep points ... not cool...

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<input type="button" id="btn_change" value="Change" />
<span id="id1_Label" class="fragenLabel">
</span>
<span id="id1_Input">
<input type="text" id="content1_edit" value="default-value" />
</span>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Mostly this should be coming from database on page-load;
    updateVal();

    $("#btn_change").click(function(){
         if( $(this).val() == "Change" )
         {
             editVal();
         }
        else
        {
            updateVal();
        }
    })
});

function editVal()
{
    $("#id1_Label").hide();
    $("#id1_Input").show();
    $("#btn_change").val("Update");
}

function updateVal()
{
    $("#id1_Label").html( $("#content1_edit").val()).show();
    $("#id1_Input").hide();
    $("#btn_change").val("Change");
}
```

Fiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/5yMZk/

Comment: sorry - i'm a newbie to stackoverflow... but in future i will remember this - thank you again :)